# Why isn't margin: 0 auto; working on my site now

Tags: html, css

So I wanted to center my header... but I stumbled across a problem right away. I want to have a container that's going to have a repeating BG(stripe lines) and in the center I want a header with the logo and menu.

Thing is, I can't get the header div to center to the parent(container).

This is the HTML part

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="css/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <dic class="header">
                <img src="images/logo.png" width="260" height="56">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

and the CCS is

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
    background-color: #00162d;
}
.container {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(../images/header_bg.jpg) repeat-x;
}
.header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

p.s. It's amazing how much you can forget if you don't code for 3 years!

Comment: Add ` * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`

Comment: If it's ok, accept pls :)

Comment: I'm pretty new to this community, not sure what you asking me to accept? Please explain and I'd be more then happy to. Appreciated your help greatly btw!

Comment: You could mark right answer as green check ;) It helps to find right answer more quickly and give me a few points

Answer (score 2):

```
<dic class="header">
```

Should be

```
<div class="header">
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dVvjm/

Comment: OMG, thanks FSou1, I had the greatest laugh of my life :D! HAHA

Comment: you should accept his answer as a valid answer if it worked for you.